# Fn keys for volume and brightness don't work on Lenovo Thinkpad e460 running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, function-keys

On my Lenovo Thinkpad e460, <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys don´t work.

I tried to enable/disable in the BIOS but it didn't help.

When I was using fedora with GNOME 3 on this device it worked perfectly. I don't know how to adjust volume or display brightness without the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I don't have an E460 but an S540 but they have similar keyboards. The picture shows an E460's keyboard:

[image: E460 keyboard]

<sup>[Source](https://www.lenovo.com/sg/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-e-series/ThinkPad-E460/p/22TP2TEE460) (emphasis mine)</sup>

The keys in the top row have two functions:

- The usual function keys <kbd>F1</kbd> … <kbd>F12</kbd>
- Special functions, such as <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>, <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>, etc.

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in the lower left has a tiny LED that indicates the default behaviour when you press e.g. 
<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>Volume Down</kbd>. If the LED is on, then it behaves as <kbd>F2</kbd>, else as <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>.

To temporarily access the other function, press <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> simultaneously.

To permanently switch the behaviour, press <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd>/<kbd>FnLk</kbd> simultaneously. The tiny LED will toggle and the keys have the other function.

In my case, the default beaviour is *LED off*, i.e. the keys have the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> etc. behaviour. In your case the default seems to be *LED on*.

Comment: thanks for response, in my laptop the fn key led always is on an dont disable in the bios. The volume, display brigness dont work

Comment: @VictorFabioRestrepoL And the LED doesn't go off when you press ESC+Fn at the same time?

Comment: not, its always is on, when the pc had windows installed it worked perfectly

Comment: did you find any sol? I am having same issue with ubuntu 20.10 on thinkpad e14.